# How to update ng-model based on selected object in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fabricjs, angularjs-ng-model

I have a slider, something like this:

```
 <md-slider aria-label="text size" step="1"
            ng-change="text.setProperty('fontSize', fontSize)"
            ng-model="fontSize" min="1" max="100">
 </md-slider>
```

Two texts are added to canvas. This is how I get properties of selected text:

```
canvas.fabric.on('object:selected', function(object) {
    if (object.target instanceof fabric.Text) {
        console.log(object.target);
    }
});
```

object.target returns an object with properties something like this: object.target.fontSize:126 and of course this for both objects are different.

How to easily update the model (the input field with the font size value) so that it would display a font size based on the selected object. Right now it shows the same value if I select any of the text objects. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call [`$apply()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) to trigger the [`$digest`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$digest) cycle so that your value updates in the view.

You can set the value of `fontSize` in your controller followed by `$scope.$apply()` like so:

```
canvas.fabric.on('object:selected', function(object) {
    if (object.target instanceof fabric.Text) {
        console.log(object.target);
        $scope.fontSize = object.target.fontSize;
        $scope.$apply();
    }
});
```

Comment: I thought that it might be easy. Thanks to you!